# php:pasar valor a select al seleccionar un valor de un combo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, poo

Buen dia tengo una pantalla la cual contiene un combo el cual me despliega la lista de proveedores  tendran alguna idea de como pasar el valor seleccionado del proveedor

mi codigo es el siguiente
orden compra.js

```
    case 'listarArticulos':
      require_once "../modelos/Articulo.php";
      $articulo = new Articulo();

      $rspta = $articulo - > listarActivosp();
      $data = Array();

      while ($reg = $rspta - > fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array(
          "0" => '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="agregarDetalle('.$reg - > idarticulo.
          ',\''.$reg - > codigo.
          '\',\''.$reg - > nombre

          '\')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
          "1" => $reg - > codigo,
          "2" => $reg - > nombre
        );
      }
      $results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1, //Información para el datatables
        "iTotalRecords" => count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
        "aaData" => $data);
      echo json_encode($results);
      break;
```

el ajax que es ordencompra.php donde selecciono el case listarArticulos

```
    case 'listarArticulos':
      require_once "../modelos/Articulo.php";
      $articulo = new Articulo();

      $rspta = $articulo - > listarActivosp();
      //Vamos a declarar un array
      $data = Array();

      while ($reg = $rspta - > fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array(
          "0" => '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="agregarDetalle('.$reg - > idarticulo.
          ',\''.$reg - > codigo.
          '\',\''.$reg - > nombre.

          '\')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
          "1" => $reg - > codigo,
          "2" => $reg - > nombre,

        );
      }
      $results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1, //Información para el datatables
        "iTotalRecords" => count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
        "aaData" => $data);
      echo json_encode($results);
      break;
```

y en Articulo.php es donde quiero tomar el valor de idproveedor

```
public function listarActivosp($idproveedor) {

$sql = "SELECT a.idarticulo,a.idcategoria,c.nombre as categoria,a.codigo,a.nombre,p.idpersona,a.stock,a.descripcion,a.precio,a.iva,a.unidad,a.imagen,a.condicion FROM articulo a INNER JOIN categoria c ON a.idcategoria=c.idcategoria INNER JOIN persona p on p.idpersona=a.idproveedor WHERE a.condicion='1' and a.idproveedor='$idproveedor'";
      return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
```

me pueden dar alguna pista o forma de como hacerlo por favor

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. ¿En  qué parte de todo tu código ya recibes el valor de tu combo ? ¿O eso tampoco lo tienes hecho? Saludos.

Comment: Hola @FernandoTorres de hecho el combo si se llena desde otro select, lo que no e logrado es  como pasar el valor del combo  al where del  select

Comment: @DavidMG muestra tu llamada ajax, en ella me imagino que para entrar al case en la seccion del data indicas el case, ahi puedes indicar el valor del where por ejemplo **data { case : 'listarArticulos', id : $('#mycombo').val() }** saludos